# Crystal reports sub reports. People in main report not in subreport

Tags: crystal-reports, subreports

I am fairly new to sub reports in Crystal Reports.

I have a MAIN report pulling out a list of Patients meeting various criteria.

I want to display in this MAIN report only the patients that DO NOT appear in my sub report.

I can link on the PATIENTID field in both reports but not sure how to only display people in the MAIN report that DONT appear in the SUBREPORT.

Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 1):

You can't link the two data sources together. What you can do here is, in the data source in the main report, filter on the patients that doesn't meet the criteria for the patients in the sub reports. Just inverse the criteria, in both reports.

If you can show in details both reports' data sources and criteria we can help more.